# JGroups state transfer of a Map with Address keys

Tags: jgroups

I am migrating an application which uses JGroups 3.6.6 to JGroups 4.0.2. The 'Address' type in JGroups 3.6.6 was serializable but due to security reasons it has been made Streamable in JGroups 4.0.2. Due to this I am facing a problem during state transfer. Here is the class I use for state transfer.

```
public class State implements Streamable {
/**
 * 
 */
private static final Logger     log                             = LogManager.getLogger(State.class);
private Map<Address, ScaleInfo> nwMap                       = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
private Set<Address>            listOfSyncedMastersInCluster    = Collections
                                                                        .newSetFromMap(new ConcurrentHashMap<Address, Boolean>());
private boolean                 hasMasterMajorityInCluster      = false;
private Address prevCoordAddress = null;
private Address currentCoordAddress = null;
private static final State      instance                        = new State();

private State() {

}

public static State getInstance() {
    return instance;
}}
```

The state transfer logic,

```
@Override
public void getState(OutputStream output) throws Exception {
    State state = State.getInstance();
    synchronized (state) {
        Util.objectToStream(state, new DataOutputStream(output));
    }
}

@Override
public void setState(InputStream input) throws Exception {
    State state = State.getInstance();
    synchronized (state) {
        state.setInstance((State) Util.objectFromStream(new DataInputStream(input)));
    }
}
```

The problem is that I can't find a way to marshal the Map with Address key. I tried debugging to see what was happening and I could see that the Map is being treated as a primitive type and JGroups tries to Serialize it. This causes an exception. Here is the code I use for implementing Streamable,

```
@Override
public void writeTo(DataOutput out) throws Exception {
    Util.writeObject(networkMap, out);
    Util.writeAddresses(listOfSyncedMastersInCluster, out);
    out.writeBoolean(hasMasterMajorityInCluster);
    Util.writeAddress(prevCoordAddress, out);
    Util.writeAddress(currentCoordAddress, out);
    out.writeUTF(Util.objectToByteBuffer(this).toString());
}
@Override
public void readFrom(DataInput in) throws Exception {
    nwMap = (Map<Address, ScaleInfo>) Util.readObject(in);
    listOfSyncedMastersInCluster = (Set<Address>) Util.readObject(in);
    hasMasterMajorityInCluster = in.readBoolean();
    prevCoordAddress = Util.readAddress(in);
    currentCoordAddress = Util.readAddress(in);
    instance = Util.objectFromByteBuffer(in.readUTF().getBytes());
}
```

1. Is there a way to marshal the 'nwMap' member variable?
2. Is there a way to implement Streamable for a user defined **singleton** class? 'State' object in this case is singleton.

Edit 1:
The second question stresses on the case with a singleton class. The problem happens when calling the `Util.objectFromStream` method which internally calls the `Util.readGenericStreamable`method. Within this method, the following block of code is executed.

```
    {
        String classname=in.readUTF();
        clazz=ClassConfigurator.get(classname, loader);
        retval=(T)clazz.newInstance();
    }
```

Calling newInstance on the singleton results in an exception. This is what I tried to convey in my question "*Is there a way to implement Streamable for a user defined **singleton** class?*".

Util.objectFromStream method is called internally while framing the replyFromBuffer method (found in RequestCorrelator) and also in setState method. Though I avoided calling objectFromStream in setState method, the internal calls from RequestCorrelator is still causing problems.

Edit 2:
Updated the second question.

Edit 3:
Refer to Bela Ban's answer and the comments below for the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd implement marshalling the hashmap by marshalling the number of entries first as an int, then iterating over the entries and marshalling each Address,ScaleInfo entry separately.

There are methods in `Util`, such as `writeAddress()` or `writeAddresses()`  that marshal an address or a list of addresses.

On the receiver side, read the int N and create a hashmap, then read N entries. `Util.readAddress()` can be used to create addresses from a byte[] array / input stream.

Re the singleton: I don't see how this is different from marshalling a non-singleton...

Comment: I have added marshalling and unmarshalling for the Map in question and it works fine. But this is only a workaround since I have the functions within the application. A more serious issue is with the instance being singleton. I have updated the question explaining the issue I face because of using a Streamable Singleton.

Comment: As of now I have avoided sending 'State' as is and modified the code to send a byte buffer after marshaling in the caller. The callee  then performs un-marshalling (with the prior knowledge of the class being a singleton). This works well for me. I would like to know if this is the right way to do it.

Comment: Sending a byte buffer always works, perhaps the best solution for a singleton such as yours.